# Woocommerce: Only one review per verified buyer

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic

By default, Woocommerce allows multiple reviews by a single user. What I want is to allow only one review from verified buyers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the single-product-reviews.php template file and add a conditional check. [How to limit users to one comment per post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137799/how-to-limit-users-to-one-comment-per-post)

Comment: Answers should be more than a link. Please post a real answer. For guidance, please see [answer]

Comment: Thanks Michael, it was enough for me. Had I known previously that WooCommerce reviews are nothing but comments for its custom post type (products), I would have figured this out earlier.

Comment: I'm glad you didn't find out for yourself, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to solve my problem through your question, thanks: D