# I want to limit registered user to 1 comment per post in Wordpress

Tags: comments, users

Good day all, I want to limit registered users to 1 comment per post in WordPress, i used this code below in my theme's function.php file and have also checked questions that may seem to have my answer on the platform all to no avail.

In this case of this it displays the message "You have commented" on the top bar of my site and does nothing.Hope to find help.

```
global $current_user, $post;
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    comment_form();
} else {
    $usercomment = get_comments(array('user_id' => $current_user->ID, 'post_id'=>$post->ID) );
    if($usercomment) { 
        echo '<p>You have commented</p>';
    } else {
        comment_form(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use this code?

Comment: You should put this code to the template file where the `comment_form()` resides.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit users to one comment per post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137799/how-to-limit-users-to-one-comment-per-post)

Comment: Theme template file! Nobody in the right mind edit files from `wp-includes`. Also, turn the debugging on during development.