# Conditional: IF current user has NOT commented on current post (not including post author)

Tags: loop, comments, single, conditional-content

I'm trying to find a way to have a conditional snippet in `single.php` where `//do something` happens if the current user has not commented on the current post.

I'm hopeless at coding but I'm guessing I need some of this...

```
is_user_logged_in()

$user_id = get_current_user_id()
```

The comment part baffles me... would this help?
[https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137799/how-to-limit-users-to-one-comment-per-post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137799/how-to-limit-users-to-one-comment-per-post?rq=1)

Comment: I added some comments to the code that you referenced. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDIT] Here is the modified code:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();          // ID of the current post.
$user_id = get_current_user_id(); // ID of the current user.
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
$is_post_author = ( $user_id && $post_author_id == $user_id );
$can_comment = $is_post_author;

/*
 * If $can_comment is not yet TRUE, then it's because either:
 *   a) The user is not the author of the post; or
 *   b) The user is not registered on the site; or
 *   c) The user is logged-out.
 */
if ( $user_id && ! $can_comment ) {
    $comment_count = get_comments( array(
        'post_id' => $post_id,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'count'   => true,
    ) );

    $can_comment = empty( $comment_count );
}

if ( ! $is_post_author ) {
    if ( $can_comment ) {
        echo 'Post your comment.';
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry, you\'ve commented. Or you can\'t comment..';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can I stretch the friendship by excluding the current user's own posts?

Comment: I've updated the code snippet. Check it out.

Comment: It's still telling me the logged in post author hasn't commented on their own current post

Comment: Sorry if this sounds stupid, but are you sure? Because that's a bit odd. I've already tested the code and it worked well on my end. But it might be caused by some custom queries by your site's theme or a plugin. Try to add `wp_reset_postdata();` before/above the `$post_id = get_the_ID();` line and see if that helps.

Comment: Definitely not sounding stupid, here's what I have (see pastebin link) in my single.php. The post author stills sees a "please leave a response" if he/she hasn't commented on his own post??

https://pastebin.com/h4yAErbz

Comment: So, post authors can always comment on their own posts, even if they've already commented? If that's so, then I had really misunderstand the whole thing about the "*excluding the current user's own posts*".

Comment: Yes post authors can comment on their own posts but I don't want them caught up in the conditional snippet :)

Comment: IF any user (except the post author) hasn't commented on the current post they are viewing THEN... thanks for being so patient :)

Comment: I've updated the code snippet. Check it out. (replace the previous one that you added to the *single.php* file)

Comment: Sorry Sally, it's still telling the post author to post a comment?

Comment: Try the updated code snippet. Hopefully, this time I got it right! =)

Comment: That's the one :) Thank you very much for taking the time to help me. I hope it helps others too.

Comment: Yep, I hope so, too. =)